# Android - Compare String with .txt file in raw folder

Tags: android, string, compare

I want to know how to compare string value with .txt file's every line and get equal value.

I get All values from .txt file but i don't understand how to compare it.
 For example

```
ABC
CBA
CCC
```

are in my .txt file,
and in my activity

```
String someText = "ABC";
```

and how to compare it with .txt file eacline.
I done below code to get .txt file values.

```
String result;
        try {
            Resources res = getResources();
            InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.out);

            byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
            in_s.read(b);
            result = new String(b);
            tx.setText(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            result = "Error: can't show file.";
            tx.setText(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("out.txt"), "UTF-8")); 

        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading 
        String mLine = reader.readLine();
        while (mLine != null) {
           //process line              
           //mLine = reader.readLine(); 
           if ("ABC".equals(mLine)){
               Toast.makeText(this, "Yuppppiiiiii", 1000).show();                  
           }
           mLine = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //log the exception
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
             try {
                 reader.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 //log the exception
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is because the way you read the file.
**you currently read all file content into a string** and this makes you difficult to compare.
Ok, now is the procedures:

1. You open the file (Create an InputStream, use the Assert, and then wrap it inside a BufferedReader)
2. You read it line by line, store value in a variable (Use readline() function of bufferreader)
3. You call the compare string function for this variable and your string (String.equal)

I hope you can understand it clearly. All remain task are about the Android docs.